# How to DELETE data from a table[Ingress db]

Tags: database, delete-file

I need to delete certain data from my table,
but I write the following:

> delete from myTable where myField = value;
>   commit;

and I get error:

> E_US0DAE DELETE on Table myTable: no GRANT or GRANT compatible permit exists.

Does anyone know why that error comes out?
I hope you can help me.

Comment: You do not have the permission to Delete, your user login needs permission granted for delete.

Comment: @RyanWilson its right.
I just changed my user, which has permissions.

Comment: ok. Does that mean you can delete from the table now?

Comment: yes,  I can already make changes to the db.